# unexpected logiclib behavior when testing string returned by system plugin

Tags: winapi, nsis

I am getting system information via the System plugin by using code similar to the [answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358195/317266). The API function is very similar except that it returns (or not) a wide char string.

While using that script on a computer that is member of a domain, I cannot understand why the logiclib test always pass in the `${else}` branch of the test. The following capture shows that `$1` is not null:

[image: variable dump]

While reading more the [NetGetDCName reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370420(v=vs.85).aspx) I think that it would be preferable to check the function returned value instead of the wide char string pointer. I am a bit confused, why does my `${If} 0 <> $1` always fails? I have checked on a virtual machine not member of a domain that `$1` equals `0` in this case. I suppose then that the `${IfThen}` test to free the memory is wrong too.

Here is the sample code:

```
!include "logiclib.nsh"
outfile "hello2.exe"

!define DEBUG `System::Call kernel32::OutputDebugString(ts)`

section

    Call GetDCName
    pop $0

    Messagebox MB_OK "DCName=$0"

sectionEnd

Function GetDCName
    ;Push the domain controler name to the stack (or an empty string if no dc)
    push $0
    push $1
    push $2
    System::Call "netapi32::NetGetDCName(i0, i0, *w 0 r1) i.r2"
    Dumpstate::debug
    ${If} 0 <> $1
        ${debug} "copy $1"
        StrCpy $0 $1
    ${else}
        ${debug} "copy empty string"
        StrCpy $0 ""
    ${endif}
    ${IfThen} $1 <> 0 ${|} System::Call "netapi32::NetApiBufferFree(ir1)" ${|}
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Exch $0
FunctionEnd
```

**Edit:** thanks to Anders, here is the corrected function:

```
Function GetDCName
    ;Push the domain controler name to the stack (or an empty string if no dc)
    push $0
    push $1
    push $2
    System::Call "netapi32::NetGetDCName(i0, i0, *i 0 r1) i.r2" ;do not convert r1 to wchar, keep the pointer to free it
    ${If} $2 = 0
        System::Call "*$1(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} .r0)"        ;get the wchar from the pointer
        ${IfThen} $1 <> 0 ${|} System::Call "netapi32::NetApiBufferFree(ir1)" ${|}  ;free the pointer
    ${else}
        StrCpy $0 ""
    ${endif}
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Exch $0
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: The string pointer could be non-null even when the function fails, always check the return value first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<>` operator is for numbers, not strings. This is not your only problem though; `*` can (normally) only be used with `i`, not `t`/`m`/`w`. The `t`/`m`/`w` types convert to and from C style strings but in your case you need the actual memory address since you have to pass it to the free function.

You need to pass `*i0r1` to NetGetDCName, then if $2 is 0 then you can extract the string with the struct syntax (`*$1(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r5)` or `*$1(w.r5)`) and finally pass $1 untouched to the free function...

Comment: Gosh, I missed the point about the string comparator. And many thanks for the `*$1(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r5)` notation (that I would not have guessed) as the `*$1(w.r5)` notation that I used crashes. Don't know why, perhaps due to my NSIS special build for long strings?

Comment: Yes you really should use the &w syntax so you don't overflow the buffer. The w.r0 syntax might only work if you set the string yourself, I don't remember exactly...